# Calling an array based on a string's value

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to call on an array in a bash script which name is defined by a string variable, like so:

```
var="array"
array=( 
1
2
3
)
```

$var will always equal the name of an array

```
#failed attempts at echoing ${array[@]}
echo "${!var}          # returns only the first value of the array

echo "${!var[@]}"      # returns 0

tempvar='${'$var'[@]}' # makes a new variable with value of "${array[@]}"
echo "${!tempvar}"     #returns 'invalid variable name'
```

I'm new at this and don't see a way to figure this out.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some unsolicited advice: if you find yourself writing code that needs this sort of feature, that's a very strong indication that you should probably be using a proper programming language and not a shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bash specific

To make a reference to the array, use a "nameref" with `declare -n`

```bash
array=(1 2 3)
var=array

declare -n a=$var

for idx in "${!a[@]}"; do echo "$idx -> ${a[idx]}"; done
a[4]="hello"
declare -p a array     # original altered by above assignment
```

outputs

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
declare -n a="array"
declare -a array=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [4]="hello")
```

To make a *copy* of the array, use an indirect variable: this is ugly

```bash
tmp=${var}[@]          # constructing a string
b=( "${!tmp}" )        # indirect variable expansion
b[4]="goodbye"

declare -p tmp b array     # original not changed
```

outputs

```
declare -- tmp="array[@]"
declare -a b=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="hello" [4]="goodbye")
declare -a array=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [4]="hello")
```

Notice how the index for the "hello" element changed in `b`: this is because the `b=("${!tmp}")` only made a copy of the array *elements*, not the *indices*.

Answer (score 0):

Beware in bash (like in ksh whose array design bash copied), arrays are not like normal arrays but *sparse arrays* so more like associative arrays with keys limited to positive integers.

Here, you can do:

```
$ array=( [12]=a [23]=b [34]=c )
$ var=array
$ tempvar_for_separated_out_keys='!'$var[@]
$ tempvar_for_separated_out_values=$var[@]
$ printf -- '- <%s>\n' "${!tempvar_for_separated_out_keys}"
bash: !array[@]: invalid variable name
$ printf -- '- <%s>\n' "${!tempvar_for_separated_out_values}"
- <a>
- <b>
- <c>
```

(yes, the one for the keys doesn't work yet).

Or you could use a nameref instead (also from ksh though with some differences).

```
$ typeset -n var=array
$ printf -- '- <%s>\n' "${!var[@]}"
- <12>
- <23>
- <34>
$ printf -- '- <%s>\n' "${var[@]}"
- <a>
- <b>
- <c>
```

Or you could switch to `zsh`, where dereferencing is done with the `P` parameter expansion flag. `zsh` arrays are arrays, though it also has proper associative arrays with keys as arbitrary strings (of any byte or character).

```
$ array=( a b c '' ) var=array
$ printf -- '- <%s>\n' ${(P)var}
- <a>
- <b>
- <c>
$ printf -- '- <%s>\n' "${(P@)var}"
- <a>
- <b>
- <c>
- <>
```

```
$ typeset -A hash=( 12 a 23 b 34 c '' empty )
$ var=hash
$ printf -- '- <%s>\n' "${(Pk@)var}"
- <>
- <34>
- <23>
- <12>
$ printf -- '- <%s>\n' "${(Pv@)var}"
- <empty>
- <c>
- <b>
- <a>
$ printf -- '- <%s> -> <%s>\n' "${(Pkv@)var}"
- <> -> <empty>
- <34> -> <c>
- <23> -> <b>
- <12> -> <a>
```

(`k` flag for the *keys*, `v` flag for the *values* (default), `@` flag inside quotes to preserve empty elements like for the Bourne shell's `"$@"`).